Azure DevOps pipeline automatically creates PAT and aborts
I'm trying to deploy my NextJS application to Azure Web Service using Azure DevOps. I've created this pipeline for automated deployment:
trigger:
  - main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  
name: $(Build.DefinitionName)_$(Build.SourceBranchName)_$(Build.BuildId)

steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '18.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

  - script: yarn install
    displayName: 'yarn install'

  - script: yarn lint
    displayName: 'yarn lint'

  - script: yarn build
    displayName: 'yarn build'

  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: 'zip'
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
      replaceExistingArchive: true

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      ArtifactName: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'Container'

  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: *******
      appType: 'webAppLinux'
      appName: *******
      package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
      runtimeStack: 'NODE|18-lts'
      startUpCommand: 'yarn start'

After the pipeline trigger, it automatically creates PAT in my account settings with today's expiration date
https://i.sstatic.net/82IQm.png
and fails with the following trace:
Got service connection details for Azure App Service: *******
Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: KuduStackTraceURL
##[error]KuduStackTraceURL https://******/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace
##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Conflict (CODE: 409)
Successfully updated deployment History at ********
App Service Application URL: *******
Finishing: AzureWebApp


I'm new to Azure pipelines, so any help would be appreciated!
Nothing I've tried seems to help


it automatically creates PAT in my account settings with today's expiration date

I can reproduce the same situation when deploying to Azure Web App.

The cause of the operation is that the Azure Web App has connected to the Azure Repo in Deployment Center.
You can navigate to Azure Web APP -> Deployment ->Deployment Center and check if the connection exists.

In this case, when the pipeline trigger(new commits exist in the repo), it will automatically create the PAT in Azure DevOps and start the sync process in deployment Center.

Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Conflict (CODE: 409)

To solve this issue, you can refer to the following methods:
Method1: You can disconnect the Azure Repos Connection in Azure Web APP -> Deployment Center.

Method2: You can check if the Web App is free tier or a paid production plan. If the configuration of the free tier does not meet the needs of your web app, you need to upgrade it.
Method3: You can restart the Azure Web App and run the pipeline again.

welp, disconnecting indeed helped in my case. many thanks, u saved my day!
